# why my controller function is not getting executed?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a simple app with database and i am having issues with controller function. It's not getting executed for some reason that i couldn't figure it out and it drove me crazy. I will be so grateful if you guys could help with me this.

userController.js

```
exports.insertUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = await MySQL.insertRecord(User, { ...req.body })
        res.status(201).send(user)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    }
}
```

insertion function in db.js

```
static async insertRecord (User, body) {
        console.log(1) // for debugging purposes
        const user = User.build(body)
        try {
            await user.save()
            console.log('Record saved to database succesfully.')
            return user
        } catch (e) {
            throw e
        }
    }
```

userRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const userController = require('../controllers/userController')
const router = express.Router()

router
    .post('/signup', userController.insertUser)

module.exports = router
```

server.js

```
(async () => {
    const express = require('express')
    require('dotenv').config()
    const path = require('path')
    const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
    const MySQL = require('./database/db')
    await MySQL.connect(Sequelize)
    const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes')

    const app = express()
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

    // setting ejs as the templating language
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
    // middlewares
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
    app.use('/user', userRouter)

    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server listening on port: ${PORT}`))
})()
```

Here my insertRecord function is not getting executed. It doesn't log 1.